# Order grouped results in a join query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables like so:

```
table_a:
id    time   name
a_1   2:30   Joe
a_2   2:35   Mike

table_b:
id    time   name
b_1   3:30   Tim
b_2   5:35   Molly

table_c:
id    tag
a_1   cats
b_1   dogs
b_2   bats
a_2   mats
```

They are joined with something like:-

```
SELECT *  FROM table_a  
JOIN table_c ON table_a.id = table_c.id  
JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = table_c.id
```

I want to be able to order all the consents of table_a by time, but also table_b. This way when it is displayed it is all in order, how can I tell it to order certain things by their respective time?

Comment: We cant all be blessed with perfect spelling!

Answer (score 1):

slap an ORDER BY at the end. The SELECT is the outermost operator of that statement.

```
SELECT * FROM (table_a JOIN table_c ON table_a.id = table_c.id JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = table_c.id) ORDER BY table_a.time, table_b.time
```

Comment: For some reason this is returning  nothing, despite there being content in all 3 of the tables.

Comment: Removing JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = table_c.id fixes it. but that rather defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by one order within the other?

If so like this

```
SELECT *  
FROM table_a  
JOIN table_c ON table_a.id = table_c.id  
JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = table_c.id
ORDER BY table_a.time, table_b.time
```